# Custom Html Module for Joomla isn't styling the code but rather just printing it to screen

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am creating a joomla template and I am trying to use Custom Html Modules. When I add code to the module ... it displays the correct elements except no canvas

This is the code I am trying to put into the module.

```
  <div class="pane1">

                <h1>Static Designs</h1>

                <div class="artBox" id="aBox">
                    <section class="slide">
                        <h1>Clouds</h1>
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
                            Canvas not supported
                        </canvas>
                    </section>

                    <section class="slide">
                        <h1>Clouds and Hearts</h1>
                        <canvas id="canvas2" width="800" height="600">
                                Canvas not supported
                        </canvas>
                    </section>

                    <section class="slide">
                      <h1>Coloured Hearts</h1>
                      <canvas id="canvas3" width="800" height="650">
                                Canvas not supported
                        </canvas>
                    </section>

                    <section class="slide">
                        <h1>Green Hearts</h1>
                        <canvas id="canvas4" width="800" height="650">
                                Canvas not supported
                        </canvas>
                    </section>

                    <section class="slide">
                      <h1>Stairs</h1>
                      <canvas id="canvas5" width="800" height="600">
                                Canvas not supported
                        </canvas>
                    </section>

                    <!-- End slides. -->

                  <!-- Begin extension snippets. Add or remove as needed. -->

                    <!-- deck.navigation snippet -->
                    <a href="#aBox" class="deck-prev-link" title="Previous">&#8592;</a>
                    <a href="#aBox" class="deck-next-link" title="Next">&#8594;</a>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Is there an option I am missing? Why isn't it registering?

```
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="customHtmlContent" style="html5" />
```

that is the include statement I am using in the content section of my template

If you need any more information just ask

Thanks!

Comment: In your editor are you writing the code in source view? If not it may be converting the characters to aschii. You can check that by viewing the source in the editor.

Comment: Yea I noticed I had originally had the code in the wrong editor but now the canvas elements won't display it takes them out all together

Comment: Have you written it in source view? If not try that and save whilst still in that view and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem By turning off all the editors in Joomla. This is done by going to the plugins manager, search for "Editor" and disable all of them and select "No Editor". This is possible with tinyMCE as well with editing the config file or the php file to allow those elements with id's and classes.

with TinyMCE I went to options and switched it to extended version and added the tags I needed (canvas and section) then it worked kinda but I needed the id's on those elements for it to work properly Then I tried turning off all editors and it worked.